# KeyDown and KeyUp Combination (e.g. Ctrl+A) KeyUp Works, Not KeyDown

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, keydown, keyup

I am trying to capture the `Ctrl+A` and `Ctrl+C` `KeyDown` combination on my `RichTextBox`.

My `KeyDown` Event is not getting `e.KeyCode` 'A' or 'C' from Combinations (e.g. `Ctrl+A`)

The `KeyDown` event is fired but only ever captures the `e.Control` key, not the `e.KeyCode` for the 'A' or 'C' etc.

I have searched SO extensively and whilst there are many similar issues, none of the solutions work for me.  Applications such as notepad, Word etc. use the MouseDown event and I can't see why I cannot.

I really want this to work on the `KeyDown` event to keep the end user experience in line with other applications.  I could potentially add the `e.KeyCode` to a `KeyPress` event following the `KeyDown`, but there are lots of SO postings telling people to avoid the `KeyPress` event.

KeyDown appears to work with the `Shift` key pressed, but not the `Control` (`Ctrl`)  key.

KeyUp Event Works:

```
Private Sub rtbMain_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles rtbMain.KeyUp

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.A AndAlso (e.Control OrElse e.Shift) Then
        'Stop
        rtbMain.SelectAll()
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.C AndAlso e.Modifiers = Keys.ControlKey Then
        'Stop
        rtbMain.SelectedRtf = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Rtf)
    End If

    If (e.KeyCode = Keys.A AndAlso e.Modifiers = Keys.Control) Then
        'Stop
        rtbMain.SelectAll()
    ElseIf (e.KeyCode = Keys.C AndAlso e.Modifiers = Keys.Control) Then
        'Stop
        rtbMain.SelectedRtf = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Rtf)
    End If

End Sub
```

KeyDown Event Doesn't:

```
Private Sub rtbMain_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles rtbMain.KeyDown

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.A AndAlso (e.Control OrElse e.Shift) Then
        'Stop
        rtbMain.SelectAll()
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.C AndAlso e.Modifiers = Keys.ControlKey Then
        'Stop
        rtbMain.SelectedRtf = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Rtf)
    End If

    If (e.KeyCode = Keys.A AndAlso e.Modifiers = Keys.Control) Then
        'Stop
        rtbMain.SelectAll()
    ElseIf (e.KeyCode = Keys.C AndAlso e.Modifiers = Keys.Control) Then
        'Stop
        rtbMain.SelectedRtf = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Rtf)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It is not that obvious how this goes wrong.  But the code does have a mistake.  Ctrl+A and Ctrl+C are keystrokes that RTB itself implements.  If you are going to intercept them yourself then you *must* set e.Handled = True to prevent RTB from doing what it does.  Which is why the mishap is not obvious, RTB already does what you do in your own code so it should be hard to see it going wrong.   Well, set e.Handled = True to make sure.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks... I think RTB only implements Ctrl+A and Ctrl+C when Multiline is set to False.  Where would I set e.Handled = True?

Comment: TextBox has that problem, not RichTextBox.  Inside the If-statements.  Do try it without this code, you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks.. Problem is, it's not getting inside the If-statement to even set e.Handled = True

Comment: There is something else wonky about this control, also the probable reason that you thought it would be useful to add the event in the first place.  Hard to guess what that might be, maybe those keystrokes are being intercepted by the form before they can get to the control.

Comment: I think you're right... For example, the very first time I Right-Hand-Mouse click on the control I get the standard RHM pop-up menu (Undo, Redo, Copy, Paste etc.).  All subsequent RHM clicks yield nothing.

Comment: Try creating a custom RTB control and overriding [**`ProcessCmdKey`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey(v=vs.110).aspx) (or override it in your current form and add an additional check for `rtbMain.Focused = True`). To check for a modifier in `ProcessCmdKey` you can do: `If keyData = (Keys.Control Or Keys.A) Then`.